# FATAL ERROR: 'com.ibm.xtq.commons.utils.wrappedruntimeexception : the root element is required ina well formed document'

Tags: java, xml, jms, ibm-mq, siebel

I am trying to run Test application using standalone **JMS** application with TextMessage(using **Siebel** message in **XML** format). We are using IBM **WebSphere MQ** specific.

I got QueueConnection, QueueSession and QueueSender objects.

I have attached sample code below. While running, replymessage is null and i got exception **"FATAL ERROR: 'com.ibm.xtq.commons.utils.wrappedruntimeexception : the root element is required ina well formed document'".**
 Exception occured in line "TextMessage replyMessage = (TextMessage)msg"
Why i am getting this exception, help me out to resolve this issue.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        factory.setQueueManager(queueManagerName);
        factory.setHostName("hostName");
        factory.setTransportType(1);
        factory.setPort(1111);
        factory.setChannel("channel");
        connection = factory.createQueueConnection();
        connection.start();
        boolean transacted = false;
       QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(transacted, 1);
       MQQueue requestQueue = new MQQueue();
        requestQueue.setBaseQueueManagerName(queueManagerName);
        requestQueue.setBaseQueueName(requestQueueName);
        requestQueue.setTargetClient(1);
        Queue replyQueue = session.createQueue(replyQueueName);
       QueueSender queueSender = session.createSender(requestQueue);

       TextMessage requestMessage = session.createTextMessage();
        requestMessage.setText(message);
        requestMessage.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);
        queueSender.send(requestMessage);

        String selector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + id + "'";
        javax.jms.QueueReceiver queueReceiver = session.createReceiver(replyQueue, selector);
        Message msg = queueReceiver.receive(timeout);

        TextMessage replyMessage = (TextMessage)msg;

        replyMessage.getText();




        }
```

Below XML content is siebel xml request(this data is sent through JMS send message)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<?Siebel-Property-Set EscapeNames='false'?>
<SiebelMessage MessageId='1-1GGX' MessageType='Integration Object' IntObjectName='GL IVR Request' IntObjectFormat='Siebel Hierarchical'>
    <GLIVRRequest>
        <TransactionName>Policy</TransactionName>
        <PolicyNumber>XYZ123</PolicyNumber>
        <AgentCode></AgentCode>
        <PostalCode></PostalCode>
        <WithdrawalAmount></WithdrawalAmount>
        <LoanAmount></LoanAmount>
        <ApplyToPremium></ApplyToPremium>
        <ApplyToPremiumAmount></ApplyToPremiumAmount>
        <RequestType></RequestType>
        <RequestItemID></RequestItemID>
        <SendMethod></SendMethod>
        <GLIMCallerFaxNumber></GLIMCallerFaxNumber>
    </GLIVRRequest>
</SiebelMessage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of exception occur when **xml file** is empty or null. Please check the xml file object. This is not siebel format xml issue.

However, if you get response as "**null**", please check the receiver part.